# How can I pass NSArray to indexed arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, arrays

I have a simple `NSArray` in `Xcode` which I'd like to pass to PHP file and use it as a loop. How can I do this?

For example, my NSArray looks like this:

```
    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"hello", @"hi", @"how are you", nil];
```

What I have done so far but no success

```
    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"hello", @"hi", @"how are you?", nil];
NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:array
                                                       options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"array=%@", array];
    NSData* data = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate:self delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url.com/file.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                          timeoutInterval:60.0];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:data];

    __block NSString *resultString;

    NSURLSessionDataTask* dataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
                                                       completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                                                           if(error == nil)
                                                           {
                                                               resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                                               NSLog(@"Data: %@",resultString);
                                                           }


                                                       }];
    [dataTask resume];
```

My PHP. I went through a tutorial [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array.asp)

```
    $array = array();
    $array = $_POST['array'];
    $arrlength = count($array);

    for ($i=1; $i <= $arrlength; $i++)
    {
        //do something
    }
```

I tried echoing the `$array` but it was empty. I know somethings about Objective-c but I have very little knowledge about PHP. My code can $_POST `NSStrings` but I'm still confused of how I can do this with `NSArray`.

If anyone could please give me some pointers or give me links on some tutorials links that will be great. I have tried searching on stackoverflow and google on how to this, but their wasn't any thing I could understand.

So my question is really simple. How can I convert `NSArray` to indexed arrays in PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing array to PHP using POST from iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676893/passing-array-to-php-using-post-from-ios)

Comment: I did have a look at that answer, but it still makes no sense to me

Comment: do you know the new objc-literal-syntax that is available since last year? `NSArray *array = @[@"hello", @"hi", @"how are you"];` it's really cool :)

Comment: @Michael thanks mike. i'll use this next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So using what you have and the other question change this:

```
NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"array=%@", array];
```

To:

```
NSMutableString *postString = [NSMutableString alloc]
for (NSString *thing in array) {
    [postString appendFormat:@"array[]=%@&",[thing stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
```

This should give you the post string you want.

Comment: In my PHP do I use it like the code I have in my question? eg. $array = $_POST['array']; ?

Comment: Yes that should work. I haven't tested it. Essentially you send your request with a proper form encoding and you can use it like how you want in php, except you need to use $i=0 instead of $i=1 because arrays start with index 0 in php.

Comment: I've got it working now. Thanks Daniel. answer accepted

Answer (score 0):

You don't just put the JSON in the HTTP body. You should send the correct `POST` HTTP Format according to [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4). You could check, how [JWURLConnection class](https://github.com/julian-weinert/JWURLConnection) does it.

**EDIT**
You basically do it like:

```
array=$_json_string;
```

Or you red it in PHP like this:

```
$post = file_get_contents("php://input");
$json_object = json_decode($post, true);
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. But I am not really a pro in this, do you know how I can post NSArray with NSURLSession? I don't want to change my whole code that is already working for NSStrings.